# How do i create a economy bot using discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

I tried creating a discord bot but i have failed alot of times, this is my most recent try...

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands

print("This might take a few seconds")
print("Please wait...\n\n")

client = discord.Client()

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='/')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    activity = discord.Game(name="test", type=3)
    await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.idle, activity=activity)
    print("Bot Online!\n")
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('secret'):
        await message.channel.send('What is the "secret" you speak of?')
        if ctx.invoked_subcommand is None:
            await message.channel.send('Shh!', delete_after=5)

client.run('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
```

I cant even get through the statues part. What im trying to do is a bot that has a economy (shop and bank). Can someone please help me

Comment: You should look at the bot framework `ext.commands` in more depth about how its used. It will help you a lot

Answer (score 1):

As @Joshua Nixon said you should use `commands.Bot` instead of `discord.Client` ([docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot))

To store all the informations you can use json, sqlite or something like mongoDB as database